# php issue with closing opening tag in logic

Tags: php, html

I have this code. I need tree cards in a row and when each card is clicked accordion body is showing in the bottom row (it should). But in first and second card its not happening because horizontal-accordion div tag is not closed yet. I don't know how I can make that to tree products shown in a row and accordion-body is showing in a new row

```
<div class="container  ">
  <?php 
  $count = 0;
  $count_row=0;
  while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_products)) {
  
      if($count_row % 3 ==0)
  {
  echo'<div class="horizontal-accordion">';
  }?>
        <div class="accordion-header " data-target="#<?php echo $count ?>">
        <div class="card text-black  hover-shadow ">
        <img src="images/<?php echo $product["photo_path"]?>" class="card-img-top"/>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $product["name"]?></h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        $count_row++;
        if($count_row % 3 ==0 )
        {
        echo "</div>";
        }
?>
  <div id="<?php echo $count ?>" class=" accordion-body collapse">
    ////////////here is my accordion body part, I just shortened it, the issue is not here/////
  </div>
 
 <?php
  $count++;
  }
 ?>
</div>
```

this code is final result, I simplified it and it looks better now, before adding php and database it was fine, working as expected, I know the issue but I'm not that much familiar with php to deal with this problem.

Comment: Check count_row for the closing tag before you increment it. Otherwise, it won't match the opening tag above.

Comment: You could probably fix this, and it would be fine, but you could maybe simplify your code by using `array_chunk` to directly split your products into chunks of three before you loops, then iterate over chunks to build your accordions, then over products inside of chunks to add your inner items.

Answer (score 0):

> ////////////here is my accordion body part, I just shortened it, the issue is not here/////

You need to print this on every 3rd iteration

Try this

```
<div class="container">
<?php
$count = 0;
$count_row = 0;

$products = [
    ["photo_path" => "product1.jpg", "name" => "Product 1"],
    ["photo_path" => "product2.jpg", "name" => "Product 2"],
    ["photo_path" => "product3.jpg", "name" => "Product 3"],
];

foreach ($products as $product) {
    if ($count_row % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<div class=\"horizontal-accordion\"> \n ";
    }
    ?>

    <div class="accordion-header" data-target="#<?php echo $count; ?>">
        <div class="card text-black hover-shadow">
            <img src="images/<?php echo $product["photo_path"]; ?>" class="card-img-top"/>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $product["name"]; ?></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $count_row++;

    if ($count_row % 3 == 0) {
        echo "\r \t </div>";


    }
    ?>


    <?php if ($count_row % 3 == 0) { ?>
        <?php $count++; ?>
        <?php echo "\n"; ?>

        <div id="<?php echo $count; ?>" class="accordion-body collapse">
            ////////////here is my accordion body part, I just shortened it, the issue is not here/////
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    
<?php } ?>
```

Tip: I used some help from escape character (`\n \r`) which greatly aid in text formatting and reduce cognitive load when you look and analyse the output

Comment: thank you for fast response. your code is working as expected, but now for every product card in a row its opening the last products accordion body in the row

Comment: Got you this increment `<?php $count++; ?>`  should have been after the accordion body part right after the closing div